# could not be able to run AIR .apk file on android emulator

Tags: android, apache-flex, android-emulator, apk, flex4.6

I have developed a mobile app in Flex 4.6, and generated a .apk file in following way

[image]

and installed on android emulator. installation is successful but while I'm trying to run that app, popup dialog appears saying that `application stopped unexpectedly Please try again`. Please tell me how to get rid of that error and run that app in android emulator. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is so simple, if you are running App on emulator you have to install air run time for emulator located in `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\runtimes\air\android\emulator\Runtime.apk` your App will run as you want. Happy Programming and Wish you all the best Dear Arshay.

Comment: How do you know my nickname `Arshay`?? I'm not sure but I think you are my friend by any chance. Ok thanks for solving my Problem Jani Love you!!!